# How to center this grid of squares?

Tags: geometry, processing

I am trying to simply produce a grid of 5 rotated rectangles. But the grid will not come out centered. Can anyone help me out?

```
int margin = 150; //padding to sides and top/bottom
int rectH = 60; // height of rectangle 
int rectW = 20; //  width of rectangle 
int n_rectangles = 5; // 5 rectangles to draw

size(800,800);
for (int x =  margin+rectW; x <= width - margin; x += (width-2*(margin+rectW))/n_rectangles) {
  for (int y =  margin+rectH; y <= height - margin; y += (height-2*(margin+rectH))/n_rectangles) {
     fill(255);
     //now rotate matrix 45 degrees
     pushMatrix();
     translate(x, y);
     rotate(radians(45));
     // draw rectangle at x,y point
     rect(0, 0, rectW, rectH);
     popMatrix();

  }
}
```

Comment: What do your functions (pushMatrix, translate, rotate,...) do ?

Comment: @PierreS. this is [Processing](https://processing.org/) and the functions are built-in.

Comment: It is Processing-specific. Basically, to rotate the squares you "push" the matrix, then pick a point to rotate it around, then rotate it, draw the square, now "pop" the matrix back into place. 

I think the issue is in the double for loop though

Comment: *"I am trying to simply produce a grid of 5 rotated rectangles"*  - the grid has 6*6 rectangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to draw single "centered" rectangles, the origin of the rectangle is `(-rectW/2, -rectH/2)`:

```java
rect(-rectW/2, -rectH/2, rectW, rectH);
```

Calculate the distance of the first rectangle center tor the last rectangle center, for row and column:

```java
int size_x = margin * (n_rectangles-1); 
int size_y = margin * (n_rectangles-1);
```

Translate to the center of the screen `(width/2, height/2)`,
to the position of the upper left rectangle `(-size_x/2, -size_y/2)`
and finally each rectangle to its position `(i*margin, j*margin)`:

```java
translate(width/2 - size_x/2 + i*margin, height/2 - size_y/2 + j*margin);
```

See the final code:

[image]

```java
int margin = 150; //padding to sides and top/bottom
int rectH = 60; // height of rectangle 
int rectW = 20; //  width of rectangle 
int n_rectangles = 5; // 5 rectangles to draw

size(800,800);

int size_x = margin * (n_rectangles-1); 
int size_y = margin * (n_rectangles-1); 

for (int i =  0; i < n_rectangles; ++i ) {
    for (int j =  0; j < n_rectangles; ++j ) {

         fill(255);

         pushMatrix();

         translate(width/2 - size_x/2 + i*margin, height/2 -size_y/2 + j*margin);
         rotate(radians(45));

         rect(-rectW/2, -rectH/2, rectW, rectH);

         popMatrix();
    }
}
```